# Windows 10 App Submission Requires Privacy Policy but my App does not collect anything. How to fix?

Tags: windows, desktop-application

I developed an app and am trying to submit it to the Microsoft store.
The app doesn’t access, collect or transmit personal data. It is a completely localized application.
In the submisssion in properties section under support info there are two check button
1 need to provide a privacy policy a valid url
2 not need
I checked option 2.
But when i upload the package (the msixupload file) it causes that what i checked above ("2 not need") to be unchecked and option 1 ("need to provide a privacy policy) to be checked and i can't unckeck.

Google has been no help. It uses runFullTrust. Would this have anything to do with it? How can I fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: @RickyKresslein Not really. But what did work for me was to create the privacy policy using a free online tool and just putting the bare minimum in. I.e. I said the application may collect information such as first name. Even though it does not. And then provided that. Microsoft let it be published :)

Comment: Yeah, I did pretty much the same thing, except I created my own on my website that just says it does not collect anything. Strange that they require this if the app doesn't collect anything.